# how can i load a display in tableview header section iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how can i display a image in tableview header section iphone ?

Answer (score 2):

Just set its view to an UIImageView :

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"foobar.png"]];
[[self tableView] setTableHeaderView:imageView];
```